# How to record user actions and then re-execute them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a web page (all done in client side code) where users can add certain page elements dynamically through different buttons.

For example, they can click a button called "Add Group" and input a group name. This will create a `<div class="customGroup">` that displays the group as the "title" among some other buttons that let them add even more elements within that newly created `<div>`.

I want to be able to store what a user did and not have it lost if they do something like close & reopen the window or reload the page. So for example, if they add a group "Foo" and refresh the page, given that the page is all HTML/JavaScript, "Foo" is lost.

Is there some way I could record their actions and re-execute them using caching/cookies? Or do I need to do it some other way? Is this even possible?

Comment: This question is very board but basically you can just store the data in localStorage and whenever the user come back, you can do something with the data stored to restore the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to keep this data around, across windows opening and closing.

You can find out what the user clicks on by attaching an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the elements you care about. The functions you pass in there can keep references to the clicked items by pushing them to an array. Then you can click them when you want to using [.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click).

As for text the users enter when the data is submitted, make sure its in localstorage as a string. On page load, you can put this data wherever you want to, so give it to an elements innerHTML and voila, you can reconstruct the page state.

Comment: Yeah thanks... I didn't know about "localstorage" before, and after researching these things it appears that I will be able to make it work using these concepts